# How does "ToList" alter the output of my EntityFramework query?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4

Hello i'm using entity framework / Vb.net 2010 .
I have a form with bindingsource to entity , and i want to know what is the difference between these 2  instructions:

1. MyBindingSource.datasource = From t in context.MyTable1 where ...some conditions
                               Select t
2. MyBindingSource.datasource = (From t in context.MyTable1 where ...some conditions
                                Select t).ToList

The problem is that when using each of them , i have different situation when add, delete or modify a record on bindingsource ( for example when using the second instruction , when i delete something on entity , the record still exists on bindingsource until i close and reopen the form or i should delete the record  from bindingsource too , if i use the first instruction when i delete from entity the bindingsource is updated instantly)

can you explain to me please ? which of them should i use ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The first returns a query, to which you can add more where clauses, ordering etc. Binding that to the data source will cause it to execute. This will maintain the link to the entites so that the binding source can update automatically.

The second executes the query and returns the list of objects. This is then bound to the data source. This list is separate from the entity, so needs to be re-read, which happens when you re-open the form.

Comment: thank you , but reading your answer , i found a strange situation when using the second instruction.If i add or delete record on entity , the bindingsource is not updated instantly, but if i update a record on bindingsource the database is updated instantly.And if i try to add a record on bindingsource when i use the first instruction sometimes i get an error " Item cannot be added to a read-only or fixed-size list "

Answer (score 0):

First one returns an IEnumerable(OfType T) and the second one a List(OfType T)